# How do I set up a C++ project in Xcode 4?

Tags: c++, xcode4, osx-snow-leopard

This probably has a really obvious answer, but I can't seem to find it.  I am trying to use Xcode 4 to program with C++, and I want to create a project, build, and run it through Xcode 4 like I do for other languages.  My problem is that I can't find the right type of project to do this.

Answer (score 44, accepted):

Check this out : http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Ey8LK7P1K94 at 2:30 he creates a C++ project.

Or try this:

1. Open XCode.
2. File/New Project...
3. In the "New Project" Assistant, expand the "Command Line Utility" group.
4. Select "C++ Tool"
5. Click "Next"
6. Give a project name and directory, then click "Finish".
7. Press Cmd-Shift-R to open the Console window. Output will appear there.
8. Click the "Build and Go" toolbar button.

Comment: 9. Spend 20 minutes or more figuring out why a brand new project won't build in xcode.  I hate xcode...

Comment: Worked perfectly, 2 minutes! ;)

Comment: xcode is simply the best IDE for mac. Netbeans is cool, but has bugs with gdb debugger, it get stuck... and that sucks.

Answer (score 3):

If you click around in the Mac OS part of New Project, there are a couple of options that I can see with a brief glance.  Under Framework & Library there is an STL C++ Library you can access, and then under System Plug-in there's a barebones c++ plug-in you can use.

Is that what you mean, or am I misinterpreting the question?

Comment: That's what I had...and it wouldn't run my project.  The command line tool does run it now though.